# Why is Doctrine mapping metadata needed?

Tags: php, doctrine

What is it for? Can I ommit it?

I already have my db schema, and I don't want to make a change in my columns definition and forget about Doctrine annotations.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you use, or know how to create your tables through the terminal with orm:schema-tool:create and update?

Comment: @raygo hi, I am new on Doctrine, im just reading it from Symfony and I come from Yii ActiveRecord where this was not needed. Thanks

Comment: Every entity object reflect the corresponding database table, and metadata gives a lot of information to Dictrine about important parameters. Metadata of properties gives information about data type of field, metadata of class give information about database name and so on. For example, if table field have type of datetime, Doctrine return value of that field not as string, but as object \DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of annotations in Doctrine. They do different things. For example:

**@Entity** tells doctrine that this class is an entity ( a table in the database). You can use other annotations to tell doctrine the name of the table for example.

```
<?php
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="users", indexes={@Index(name="search_idx", columns={"name", "email"})})
*/
class User
```

**@Column** will tell doctrine the info about each entity variable (each table column)

```
/** @Column(type="string", length=120) */
```

You can set up inheritance with the annotations

```
/**
* @Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\Post")
* @Table(name="posts")
* @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
* @DiscriminatorMap({"text"="Post","video"="VideoPost"})
*/
```

You can use them to create associations between entities

```
/**
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Post", mappedBy="user")
*/
private $posts;
```

And for many other things. One of the neat features, is that after you have all your entities defined, you can use the [doctrine tool](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html) to create your tables just by doing `doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` or update them by doing `doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force` .

Also once your entities are associated, its easier to access all entities and their associations.

In the beginning I didn't really understand why to use annotations but when I started to use them, it made my job way easier. Try going through [this ebook](http://www.doctrine-project.org/downloads/pdfs/manual-2-0-vi.pdf), it will make it easier for you to understand Doctrine and its uses.